# unterminated string literal error for a django template tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following snippet of code which gives me unterminated string literal error

```
$(function() {
             $('#addDropdown').click(function() {
             var $d = $('{{ form |bootstrap }}').fadeIn().delay(1000);   
             $('#dropdownContainer').append($d);
             });
             });
```

I have looked [unterminated string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296402/unterminated-string-literal) question
and found that it is because multiline problem.My {{ form |bootstrap }} has multiple lines of code as mentioned in the question.So how do I handle the problem

Comment: add }); at the end of code as this is to close your $(function(){

Comment: I think you want to render the form somewhere else than in the javascript and then just find it via some class/id selector and call `fadeIn()` on the found element

Comment: I want to add multiple(unknown number given by user by button clicks) forms to a div.Each form contains a dropdown.Fade in is just to show the transition of adding the element smoothly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, to use with JavaScript, you should use `|escapejs` filter:

`var $d = $('{{ value|escapejs }}');`

However, as a matter of best practice you'd better put `{{ form|bootstrap }}` in HTML, and use JavaScript just to fade in:

```
<div id="djangoForm" style="display:none">{{ form|bootstrap }}</div>
<script>
    $('#addDropdown').click(function() {
         $('#dropdownContainer').append($('#djangoForm'));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks The second solution was what I was looking for

Comment: Can I do it variable number of times instead of doing only once??

Comment: Variable number of times doing what? Can you clarify or give an example?

Comment: Like Add a form as many times as user clicks.Suppose if I click twice I must display two forms

Comment: Ah! In that case you may need to clone content of `$('#djangoForm')` instead of appending it: `$('#dropdownContainer').append($($('#djangoForm').html()));` - try this

Comment: p.s. sorry, please use `.html()`, not `.innerHtml()` (I've just fixed my comment above)

Comment: Last question how do I hide <div id="djangoForm" style="display:none">{{ form|bootstrap }}</div>

Comment: Cool I I put fadeIn() for djangoForm instead of dropDownsContainer awesome very detailed explaination thanks