# Django Template Error when checking if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, python, django

I working on a Django template in Javascript where I'm checking if the user is logged in before displaying a button inside of a list element. For some reason, I'm getting the error:
`Could not parse the remainder: '% if user.is_authenticated %' from '% if user.is_authenticated %'`

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
$list.append("<li class='list-group-item'>Artist: {{form_artistSelect}}  Location: " + venues[i].city + ', ' + venues[i].region +' Venue: ' + venues[i].name + 
       "Date: " + dates[i] + "tickets status: " + ticket_statuses[i] + "<br><a href = '" + ticket_urls[i] +"'" + "> ticket link</a>  
       {{% if user.is_authenticated %}} //This line is causing the error
            <button id ='invite'type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' venue= " +venues[i] +" date = "+ dates[i] +"ticket_url = "+ticket_urls[i]+" artist = {{form_artistSelect}} >Invite a friend</button>  <button id = 'save' type='button' class='btn btn-primary-outline'> Save concert</button> 
        {{% endif %}}
            </li>");
```

Why is the if statement being parsed as the modulus operator? I have the same syntax in other parts of the file and that has been working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using some extra brackets, try with:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

instead of:

```
{{% if user.is_authenticated %}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but now I'm getting a ```SyntaxError: unterminated string literal``` Am I missing a close quote somewhere? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: I think it's related to JS formatting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296402/unterminated-string-literal

Comment: And don't forget to remove the extra brackets of endif! :)