# Why is this function not being invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is below function `update()` not updating ? Is the structure of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/63/) correct ?

fiddle code :

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="toupdate">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    update();
});

function update(){
    $('#toupdate').remove();
    alert('removed');
    $('body').append('<div id="toupdate">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>
    </div>');
}
```

Comment: Why is your script hanging out after the body element? Why is it not in a <script type="text/javascript"> tag in the head element?

Comment: @thatidiotguy it actually wasn't – he just pasted literally what was in the fiddle. I fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have new lines in a JavaScript string like that.  Also the `</script>` maybe causing the JS to stop.

```
$('body').append('<div id="toupdate"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></scr'+'ipt></div>');
```

Comment: some additional resources: [script tag as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string) and [whitespace and semicolon insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons)