# javascript Token var

Tags: javascript

I keep getting a error saying unexpected token var

on these lines

```
var isSplash =true;
//------DocReady-------------
$(document).ready(function()
if(location.hash.length == 0){
location.hash="!/"+$('#content > ul > li').eq(2).attr('id');
```

Help please im a n00b at javascript

thanks

Comment: so which is it, JavaScript or Java?  The line above is valid JS, not Java.

Comment: Show us a few lines of context.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown. What's above and below it?

Comment: You've probably forgotten a `;` on the line(s) immediately before this one.

Comment: Above and below: }
//--------global-------------
var isSplash =true;
//------DocReady-------------
$(document).ready(function()
    if(location.hash.length == 0){
        location.hash="!/"+$('#content > ul > li').eq(2).attr('id');
    }

Comment: @user1612508: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line itself is perfectly valid javascript. The line before it, however, is most likely not. If your interpreter is expecting a closing brace `}` or closing paren `)` and it sees "var" instead, you will get the error message `Unexpected token: var`.

Check the line before the error for any syntax errors.

edit: The line before has a closing script tag as a string. The browser will see this as a closing script tag, regardless of the fact that it is in a string, and break the rest of your script.

To fix the issue, simply split your string in the middle of the closing script tag. e.g.

```
document.write('<script src="'+ url + '" type="text/javascript" ></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string).

Comment: The line before that is a comment stating //--------global-------------//

Comment: @user1612508 the interpreter skips over comments, what is the line before that?

Comment: //----Include-Function----
function include(url){ 
  document.write('<script src="'+ url + '" type="text/javascript" ></script>'); 
}

Comment: @user1612508 there's your problem. change `</script>` to `</scr' + 'ipt>` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string)

Comment: @jbabey that code worked for that line but now im getting an error on this line:  if(location.hash.length == 0)  saying Unexpected token if

Comment: @user1612508 are you not paying attention? look on the line before it :P

Comment: @jbabey lol i told you im a n00b it says $(document).ready(function() thats it

Comment: @user1612508 since the `scr' + 'ipt` resolved the issue you posted in your question, i'd suggest accepting my answer (if it helped) and posting another question for this new problem.

Comment: Now im getting a error saying Unexpected token {