# Embed MvcHtmlString containing <script> with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvchtmlstring

The following method of embedding some `Html` from a `string` in a `<div>` with Javascript (using some JQuery) works:

```
var div = $('#someId');
var testHtml = '<script></script><div>dummy Content</div>';
div.html(testHtml);
```

The Html code gets embedded and displayed in the div. If I put some `alert('Test')`-statement in the `<script>` tags, the alert would show up.

What also works is this:

```
<div id="someId">@MvcHtmlString.Create("<script></script><div>dummy Content</div>")</div>
```

However I need to pass a `MvcHtmlString` to a javascript function and then embed this string with javascript.

This works if there is no javascript code inside the string:

```
var div = $('#someId');
var inputItem = '@MvcHtmlString.Create("<div>dummy Content</div>")';
div.html(inputItem);
```

However if there is javascript content inside the string, the `<script>`-part does not get embedded and the content doesn't get displayed properly.

So this doesn't work properly:

```
var div = $('#someId');
var inputItem = '@MvcHtmlString.Create("<script></script><div>dummy Content</div>")';
div.html(inputItem);
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work? Is there a simple trick to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know in which browser you've tested (I've tested in IE8 and Chrome22) but your original example is also not working:

```
var div = $('#someId');
var testHtml = '<script></script><div>dummy Content</div>';
div.html(testHtml);
```

Check this [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/jqhEB/)

Because you cannot have `"</script>"` inside a JS string because the browsers interpreat it as the closing `<script>` tag. See this SO question: [Script tag in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string)

So the solution is the same for you so don't have directly the `</script>` inside the string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = $('#someId');
    var testHtml = '@MvcHtmlString.Create("<script>alert(\"test\");</sc' + 'ript><div>dummy Content</div>")';
    div.html(testHtml);
</script>
```

You can also chek this in action in this [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/jqhEB/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a fake attribute type to script tag other than " text/javascript" escape content.
Ex:

```
var inputItem = '@MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type="text"></script><div>dummy Content</div>")';
```

Remove later this attribute could make the trick.
But as i dont have idea how works MvcHtmlString, im really not sure it can be a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The `MvcHtmlString.Create` method creates HTML that is encoded and strips HTML script tags.

Use `@Html.Raw("htmlstring")` to give you the raw HTML value of the string without stripping the tags.

```
var div = $('#someId');
var inputItem = '@Html.Raw("<script></script><div>dummy Content</div>")';
div.html(inputItem);
```

Comment: `MvcHtmlString.Create` method encodes nothing but Razor does when the `@` is used. So `@MvcHtmlString.Create(@"<script></script>")` outputs just fine `<script></script>` and `Html.Raw` internally eventually calls the same code as `MvcHtmlString.Create`...

Comment: msdn documentation states that `MvcHtmlString.Create` method "Creates an HTML-encoded string using the specified text value" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461471(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: maybe the documentation is missleading but you can check yourself in the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/03357424caf5#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fMvcHtmlString.cs) that nobody is HTML encoding what you pass into `MvcHtmlString.Create`