# <script></script> tags inside of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin that I found from searching the web called [Apprise](http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-The-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery). It has worked well for what I have needed thus far. But, I want to apprise the facebook login plugin and to to that I need to following code:

```
<fb:login-button scope='email,publish_stream'>
Login
</fb:login-button>  

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '123456789',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location = '/fb_redirect.php';
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
```

Anything that you want to be apprised can be done by putting

```
apprise();
```

in the javascript. However, putting the `<script></script>` tags inside of the JS code (`apprise();`) causes all sorts of confusion because it's not clear where the JS code ends.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't put `<script>` tags inside javascript, you'll need to do something like `'<scr' + 'ipt>'` to do that, but I don't see any script tags ?

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are trying to include `<script></script>`

Comment: The first block of code needs to be placed inside of apprise();

Comment: `apprice('hello')` seems to be an attractive replacement of `alert('hello')`... how does writing `apprice('<script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() {...};</script>')` help??????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method that works in both `<script>` blocks and inline Javascript is `\uxxxx`, where `xxxx` is the hexadecimal character code.

- `<` - `\u003c`
- `>` - `\u003e`
- `"` - `\u0022`
- `'` - `\u0027`
- `\` - `\u005c`
- `&` - `\u0026`

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

HTML:

```html
<div onClick="alert('Hello \u0022>')">click me</div>

<script>
    var s = 'Hello \u003c/script\u003e';
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to break up the close script tag, if I'm reading your question right:

```
var test = '...... </scr'+'ipt>......';
```

[Script tag in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking up the tags:

```
apprise('<scri' + 'pt>alert("hello");</sc' + 'ript>');
```

Comment: This probably isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: Looks to be pretty much what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I think they want to *alert* a Facebook logon prompt.  I kinda doubt this'll work..

Answer (score 1):

You need just to escape the `/` character:

*BAD*, exception

```
<script>
    var html = "<script></script>";
</script>
```

*GOOD*

```
<script>
    var html = "<script><\/script>";
</script>
```