# </script> in string ends script section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to use JQuery to append a string to a div.

This string will be HTML, and occassionally users will be using the script tags inside the string.

Unfortunately, when the browser reads `</script>` inside the string, it ends the section and prints out all the following javascript into the browser. Obviously, we don't want that.

Is there a way to get the browser to not parse anything inside the string?

An example of this might be an Adsense ad being appended to the div.

Comment: Please add jsfiddle link

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Note, if an adsense ad is appended to an already loaded page, your already loaded page will be nuked due to `document.write`, though since you're freely allowing javascript, they could do that directly too.

Comment: You can just escape the slash in the string: `"<\/script>"`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884134/script-script-tags-inside-of-javascript-code/14885679#14885679

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a backslash (`\`) to escape the slash in the `<script>` close tag so that it doesn't close the actual `<script>` element:

```
var foo = document.write('<script src="somewhere.js"><\/script>');
```

This is often used when loading a script from a CDN with a local fallback:

```
<script src="//cdn.example.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.jQuery) document.write('<script src="/assets/js/jquery.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The workaround way for the problem is using:

```
"</scr"  + "ipt>"
```

Ugly, annoying, but **working!**