# Using script tags within script break the script

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

Essentially, I have a script tag within my script.

```
(generic HTML)
<script>
function asdf(){
    document.getElementById('jkl').innerHTML = "<script>(another script goes here)</script>"
}
</script>
(generic HTML)
```

Unfortunately, the first `</script>` tag is listened to, not the second. Is there any way to "comment" it, like butting a back slash in front of quotes?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There's probably a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break your inside script string into two pieces like this:

```
<script>
function asdf(){
    document.getElementById('jkl').innerHTML = "<script>(another script goes here)</scr" + "ipt>"
}
</script>
```

Otherwise the HTML parser will think that the inner `</script>` closing tag is closing the opening tag, and this will cause problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! I didn't think of it that way :P