# Different way of adding a </script> tag within a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, gridster

So I have a situation where I am using Gridster.js and I am building the page from a serialized JSON object that can include a closing script tag. I have created a JS fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/bradtaylorsf/Hk357/3/

I tried to use the method here "[Using script tags within script break the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162699/using-script-tags-within-script-break-the-script)"

```
    "</scr"+"ipt>"
```

vs

```
    </script>
```

but that did not work either. The template renders but the twitter widget does not actually load. Here is the full code

```
    var gridster;

    $(function(){

          gridster = $(".gridster > ul").gridster({
            widget_base_dimensions: [350, 215],
            widget_margins: [5, 5],
            min_cols:2,
            resize: {
                enabled: false
            },
          }).data('gridster');

        var serialization = [{"col":1,"row":3,"size_x":2,"size_y":1,"html":"\n\t\t\nhello form\n\n\t"},{"id":"widget1","col":1,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":2,"html":"\n\t\t\n<iframe id=\"twitter-widget-0\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\" class=\"twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered\" title=\"Twitter Timeline\" width=\"350\" height=\"400\" style=\"border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px;\"></iframe>\n<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+\"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");</script>\n\n\t"}];

        gridster.remove_all_widgets();
            $.each(serialization, function() {
                gridster.add_widget('<li>'+this.html+'</li>', this.size_x, this.size_y, this.col, this.row);
            });

        gridster.disable();



    });
```

Comment: Your code should be included within the question. A fiddle is a helpful extra, nothing more.

Comment: There you go... full code added...

Answer (score 0):

The first I noticed on your JSFiddler is that your named array has a bad escape code in it:
 - form\n\n\t"} should be
 - form\n\n\t\"}

Next why don't you do something like:

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.innerHTML = "// script content";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( fileref );
```

Here is a function that does everything:

http://www.qlambda.com/2012/01/add-script-tags-to-dom-dynamically.html