# Javascript code generator

Tags: javascript, html

I came up with an idea for a javascript thing that lets the user write in a message.
Then they can click generate and it will show them code they can copy and paste onto a webpage to use.

I created the javascript program and it works great. Now I want to let the user fill in the form and generate the code. This is where im kinda stuck. I tried making a string var and making it equal the code (I put all the code on one line, got rid of the  tags and left only the  tags and the html code.

I will add the code to a textarea when it works but it does not seem to want to.

On my page: (generate is called when the user clicks a button)

```
 <script>

   function Generate()
  {
  var generatedCode = "<script> </script> hello";
  document.getElementById("codeArea").value = generatedCode;
  }
  </script>
```

in the html area:

```
 <textarea rows="6" cols="51" id="codeArea">
```

currently this shows up on the top of the page:

```
 hello"; document.getElementById("codeArea").value = generatedCode; }
```

Comment: You should escape **all** *non-HTML* entities / text-nodes properly - see this related post: [HtmlSpecialChars equivalent in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4835406/1238344)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string

Answer (score 2):

The `</script>` tag in the script is interpreted as the end tag of your script, and

```
 hello";
 document.getElementById("codeArea").value = generatedCode;
 }
```

is interpreted as text, as it's outside the script. Try with

```
"<script> <\/script> hello"
```

or

```
"<script> </scr" + "ipt> hello"
```

`</script>` shouldn't appear inside a script, not even as part of a string literal.

Comment: Wouldn't escaping that forward slash be easier? like this: `var generatedCode = "<script> <\/script> hello";`

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes, it would. Added.