# set a Blob as the "src" of an iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, blob

The following code work perfectly in Chrome

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var blob = new Blob(['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'], {type : 'text/html'});
var newurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = newurl;
}
</script>
```

But it is not working with IE. Can some one please tell me what is wrong here.

The iframe "src" also set to the blob as shown below.

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="blob:0827B944-D600-410D-8356-96E71F316FE4"></iframe>
```

Note: 
I went on the `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob)` path as well but no luck so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri IE 11 has only got partial support for Data URI's. It states support is limited to images and linked resources like CSS or JS, not HTML files.

Non-base64-encoded SVG data URIs need to be uriencoded to work in IE and Firefox as according to this specification.

Comment: Yes this is a limitation in IE at the moment

Answer (score 4):

An example I did for Blob as a source of iFrame and working great with one important **CAUTION / WARNING**:

```
const blobContent = new Blob([getIFrameContent()], {type: "text/html"});
var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
iFrame.src = URL.createObjectURL(blobContent);
parent.appendChild(iFrame);
```

iFrame with Blob is not auto redirect protocol, meaning, having `<script src="//domain.com/script.js"</script>` inside the iframe `head` or `body` won't load the JS script at all even on Chrome 61 (current version).

it doesn't know what to do with source "blob" as protocol. this is a BIG warning here.

**Solution:** This code will solve the issue, it runs mostly for VPAID ads and working for auto-protocol:

```
function createIFrame(iframeContent) {
    let iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    iFrame.src = "about:blank";
    iFrameContainer.innerHTML = ""; // (optional) Totally Clear it if needed
    iFrameContainer.appendChild(iFrame);

    let iFrameDoc = iFrame.contentWindow && iFrame.contentWindow.document;
    if (!iFrameDoc) {
    console.log("iFrame security.");
    return;
    }
    iFrameDoc.write(iframeContent);
    iFrameDoc.close();
}
```

Comment: there is no limitation: just try out https://jsfiddle.net/z4ytwha8/1/
It works like a charm with FF, Chrome and Edge. You have to escape the </script> tags, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string

Comment: as in Can I Use Blobs supported since IE10.
https://caniuse.com/#search=Blob

Comment: Thanks!, you pointed me in the right direction: I used `new Blob([str], { type: "application/javascript" })` for a script src

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem with IE. However, I've been able to get the download/save as piece working in IE 10+ using [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

```
function onClick(e) {
    var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-download.json";
    var json = JSON.stringify(data),
        blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"});

   saveAs(blob, fileName);      

   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
};

$('#download').click(onClick);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/o0wk71n2/ (based on answer by @kol to [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link))

Comment: The download/save is ok for me too. But do you have any idea why it is not working with iframe