# Print an iframe with Google Datastudio from a parent html

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain, looker-studio

I have a Data studio dashboard embeded and I want to add a function to print the dashboard but it seems that for the CORS restrictions it is not possible to do this

is any work around this ?
I found this  but it doesn't seem to work
[print a pdf via iframe (cross domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164362/print-a-pdf-via-iframe-cross-domain)

I have this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
//  window.print();
 $("#printf").get(0).contentWindow.print();



  });
});



</script>
</head>
<body>



<iframe  width="1000" height="400" id="printf" name="printf" src="https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/0B5FF6JBKbNJxQ1hMRzRiVDlobVU/page/jR7H"></iframe>


<button>Print </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this is not possible. The answer you linked to is quite old when it comes to web standards, and that workaround has been closed by Chrome and Firefox. This is for good reason; if you could print a cross-origin iframe easily, than a hacker could embed an iframe with a URL like `https://totallynotrealfakebank.com/my-account/tax-info` which displays your social security number, capture the content with something like `html2canvas`, and steal your information.

The easiest workaround is to have users open the embed in a new tab:

```html
<a href="https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/0B5FF6JBKbNJxQ1hMRzRiVDlobVU/page/jR7H" target="_blank">Open Dashboard</a>
```

Or, if you *really* wanted a print button, you could use a third-party API that generates a screenshot based on a URL (like https://apiflash.com), or host your own with something like [node-webshot](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot). And have the print button prompt for a download of a generated image file, or embed the generated screenshot in a *same-origin* iframe and use `iframe.contentWindow.print()`.

---

Hopefully at some point Google Data Studio will let users embed Javascript and/or custom Apps Scripts into dashboards. If they ever do, that would be the best solution, since the code would be running in the same origin.