# JavaScript passing String Array to String literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, string

I want to pass Array of string values to a string literal as follows

Code :

```js
var array = ['1','2556','3','4','5'];
...
...

var output = `
<scr`+`ipt>
    window.stringArray = [`+ array +`]
</scr`+`ipt>

`
```

Output :

```
<script>
    window.stringArray = [1,2556,3,4,5]
</script>
```

Desired Output:

```
<script>
    window.stringArray = ['1','2556','3','4','5']
</script>
```

I've tried to not string the arrays and string it inside the multiline string, but the values are too long for int to handle and it breaks e.g. [888555985744859665555] this will turn into [888555985744859665500] and it's a push on the memory, easy to use string regardless!
Next I've tried to use map function within the inline string like this

```
`[`+ array.map(String) +`]`
```

I can't add any more lines to the output string mentioned above, code can be modified within the one line or added above it!

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the array. In addition just escape the `/` instead of using concatenation on the tag name - [it's easier to read, and more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string#comment1716150_1659762).

```js
const array = ['1','2556','3','4','5'];

const output = `
  <script>
    window.stringArray = ${JSON.stringify(array)}
  <\/script>
`;

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `JSON.stringify`? It works perfectly for your use case!

```js
var array = ['1','2556','3','4','5'];

var output = `
<scr`+`ipt>
    window.stringArray = `+ JSON.stringify(array) +`;
</scr`+`ipt>

`;

console.log(output);
```

You can read more about the usage of `JSON.stringify` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Didn't crossed my mind. Appreciate it